# Python, Excel sharing violation with python automatic inventory balance checking

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, smtp

First I have to say that I just started **Python** programming. I do automatic inventory balance checking, mainly as a hobby.

I need help with my program...

This opens the excel file and looks for the value `0`, in the `B` column.
if there is a `0` in the column which means that the part has run out, the code will send an **e-mail** with the title of the article from column `A`

When I did the debugging I noticed if i update the the Excel file that code uses in Excel at the same time the program happens to read the table, i get `"Excel sharing violation error"`

this is not a big problem because the final program will read the file once or twice a day but there is a small chance of an error, probably something else will crash, hopefully not.

I tried all these common ways with Excel
-Authorize Indexing for file Folders
-Permitting Sharing Wizard
-Saved file to a different location
-Renamed file
-i don't use third party Antivirus program

So would you have any tips on how i can improve the code, get rid of the above error and continue learning.

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import BOTTOM,Label, Menu
import os
import smtplib
import datetime
import time
from time import sleep
import pandas as pds

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Timer')
sec = 0

def timer():
    global sec
    sec += 1
    time['text'] = sec
    time.after(1000, timer)

time = Label(root, fg='black')
time.pack()
contact_num = os.environ.get("Contact_number")
contact_email = os.environ.get("Contact_email")
L = Label(root, text="Automatic warehouse alarm").pack()
L_2 = Label(root, text="START, Run program").pack()    
root.title("Warehouse 1.4.2")
root.geometry("460x360")

class get_data:
    def get_empty_stock(self):
        while(True):
            Email_adress = os.environ.get("email_user")
            Email_password = os.environ.get("email.password")
            file = ("C:\Exel_files\SpareParts_Vers25.xlsx")
            try:    
                dataFrame = pds.read_excel(file)
            except PermissionError:
                    print("PermissionError")
            else:
                pass        
            booleans = []
            for Amount in dataFrame.Amount:
                if Amount <= 0:
                    booleans.append(True)
                else:
                    booleans.append(False)
                if True in booleans:
                    empty_stock =  dataFrame.loc[dataFrame.Amount <= 0]
                    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587) as smtp_server:
                        time_date = datetime.datetime.now()
                        time = time_date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                        date = time_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
                        smtp_server.ehlo()
                        smtp_server.starttls()
                        smtp_server.ehlo()
                        smtp_server.login(Email_adress,Email_password)
                        subject = "Warehouse"
                        body = f"""{empty_stock}\nPart is out of stock
                        {date}\n
                        {time}\n
                        """
                        msg = f"subject: {subject}\n\n{body}" 
                        smtp_server.sendmail(Email_adress,Email_adress, msg)
                        sleep(25)
           
    def __init__(self):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.get_empty_stock)
            t.start()
                       
Start = tk.Button(root, text = "START", width= 25, command=lambda:[get_data(),timer()]).pack()        
Stop = tk.Button(root, text = "QUIT", width= 25, command= root.quit).pack(side=BOTTOM)
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
helpmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='menu', menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label=contact_email)
helpmenu.add_command(label=contact_num)
helpmenu.add_command(label= "Exit", command=root.quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multi-user sharing violation, consider copying the last saved instance of Excel file using a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) and point `read_excel` to this temp file which is automatically deleted after the `with` context:

```py
import shutil
import tempfile
...

file = "C:\Exel_files\SpareParts_Vers25.xlsx"

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
   # COPY EXCEL FILE TO TEMP FILE
   shutil.copyfile(file, tmp.name)
   try:    
       # READ IN TEMP FILE
       dataFrame = pds.read_excel(tmp.name)
   except PermissionError:
       print("PermissionError")
```